# How to return user claim when using ResourceOwnerPassword grant type

Tags: c#, oauth, .net-core, identityserver4

A bit of background info: I am in the process of upgrading our Oauth server to an identity server.  We are using IdentityServer4 for this.

Due to backwards compatibility I need to create something like a service account which will allow me to impersonate a user.  I think what i am after is something like a twitter Oauth1 type of client.   I have been trying to use [GrantTypes.ResorceOwerPassword](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)

The Client:

```
 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "ServiceAccountAccess",
                    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    // secret for authentication
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    // scopes that client has access to
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "api.full_access"
                    },
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                }
```

My User:

```
 new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "password",
                Claims = new []
                {
                new Claim("name", "Alice"),
                new Claim("website", "https://alice.com")
            }
            },
```

Usage:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ServiceAccountAccess", "secret");
      var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api.full_access");
```

Now this does work I am able to login.  However the problem i am having is that i have no way of seeing this is alice.   I have tried to do a user info.

UserInfo call

```
  // Get UserInfo
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
  var response = await client.GetAsync(disco.UserInfoEndpoint);
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
  }
  else
  {
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
  }
```

Results:

This is returning with a "Unauthorized forbidden"

I need to know who this user is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in order to access the user info you need to include profile and openid scopes

The Client:

```
 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "ServiceAccountAccess",
                    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    // secret for authentication
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    // scopes that client has access to
                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        "api.full_access" ,
                         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                    },
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
                }
```

Usage:

```
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ServiceAccountAccess", "secret");
      var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api.full_access profile openid");
```

UserInfo call

```
  // Get UserInfo
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
  var response = await client.GetAsync(disco.UserInfoEndpoint);
  if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
  }
  else
  {
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
  }
```

Results:

```
{"name":"Alice","website":"https://alice.com","sub":"1"}
```

Update:

I just found this in the documentation

> The access token will now contain a sub claim which uniquely
>   identifies the user. This “sub” claim can be seen by examining the
>   content variable after the call to the API and also will be displayed
>   on the screen by the console application.

Which means that I don't need to request it from userinfo the subject id is in the claims within the access token returned